# issue working with bootstrap panel collapse

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing an issue working with panel collapse where I have a to create dynamic data-target and id's for panel because I have list of items in ng-repeat but the problem is the collapsible panel is not in the scope of the triggering panel

I have the html code below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4" ng-repeat="topics in oJdDetails.topics">
        <a style="cursor:pointer" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{'#'+'collapse'+'_' + $index}}" ng-click="fngetQList(topics,$index)">
            <p class="col-xs-3">{{topics}}</p>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign col-xs-1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="{{'collapse'+'_' + index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <p class="col-xs-6">Question Lists</p>
                    <div class="input-group col-xs-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search" ng-change="fnSearchQList(search)">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Search question " activetooltip aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="fnshowInputQList()">
                        <div class="row">
                            <span class="col-xs-8">Add Question List</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign col-xs-4" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the controller code is

```
$scope.fngetQList = function(topics,index) {
        $scope.index = index;
    };
```

the array of topics is for example:["html","css","angular"]

I have no idea what I am doing wrong but when I click on 1st item the panel is getting opened with "collapse in " class but when I click on second item there still the "collapse in " class is getting appened which results in closing of the panel instead of opening the panel.


Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/furkankatman/trgrjwf1/7/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide a live example?fiddle

Comment: @Fast Snail here i have this example ,but in this i could see that collapse in class is not gettiing appended 
https://jsfiddle.net/trgrjwf1/50/

Comment: here is a plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/NfNUYe2EyqjGDXUBUvZC?p=preview

Comment: yes thanks for the link but still my problem is the same as in the plunker link if i click on html the panel is getting opened but when i click on css it is getting closed

Comment: i guess bootstrap trigger event before angular change target.if you write 3 divs like this https://plnkr.co/edit/5e35x5KfZcHh6K8MTvVl?p=preview you can see it's working.but it's not the solution